# Two Different Links for Same Product - WooCommerce

Tags: php, functions, woocommerce-offtopic, htaccess

The idea here is to publish one WooCommerce Product to 2 unique Links. This way, we can edit the product at both Links in one location. However, can use functions.php to alter content by reading the unique Permalink structure.

Elaboration: We have one section of our website where product pricing is hidden and another section of our website where product pricing is shown. I know that this is possible if we duplicate each product, but then we are stuck editing two products for simple updates. This is why my idea is to push one product to 2 unique Links, and then use functions.php to read the unique permalink structure for those that should have a hidden price tag

Any ideas on whether or not this is possible and/or how to accomplish?

I have tried the following plugin, but it does not serve the purpose: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-external-product-urls-for-woocommerce/